# Setting fountainwiki variables in vim

Tags: vim, global-variables

I've installed the [fountainwiki](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3945), a plugin that offers wiki like features for fountain - the markdown language for screenwriting. In the help file for fountainwiki a lot of options are listed for example:

```
Auto-indent scheme: 0 = off, 1 = on (default).
let g:Fountainwiki_Auto_Indent = 0
```

I can't get those options to work. I've tried this (in normal mode):

```
:let g:Fountainwiki_Auto_Indent = 0
```

And I've tried adding this to .vimrc:

```
let g:Fountainwiki_Auto_Indent = 0
```

Neither works to switch off auto-indentation (tried other options as well).

What would be the correct way to execute the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration variables must usually be put into your `~/.vimrc`, because that is the first config file read when Vim starts up, and the plugins read the configuration override once on startup.

You can verify the value via

```
:echo g:Fountainwiki_Auto_Indent
```

If you have problems with a particular plugin, its author is the best resource; email him or open an issue in the accompanying issue tracker, if there is any.

Comment: I wrote the author more than three weeks ago and no reply. Conclusion is that it's a problem with the plugin and that it's un-maintained. Actually switched to emacs meanwhile and that handles the fountain syntax really well.

Comment: Since the last script update is from 2 years ago, that's a fair assumption, too bad. Good luck with Emacs, though; it's a fine editor, too!